# DB Context is created every time I call an Action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I faced a problem while creating my Web Application. My goal is to create a Database each time I run my app. Here's how I do it. My Context class:

```
namespace MyWebApplication.Data
{
    public class MediaPlayerContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TrackEntity> TrackContextEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AlbumEntity> AlbumContextEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ArtistEntity> ArtistContextEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BandEntity> BandContextEntities { get; set; }

        public MediaPlayerContext(DbContextOptions<MediaPlayerContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            MediaPlayerInitializer.Initialize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Initializer class:

```
namespace MyWebApplication.Data
{
    public class MediaPlayerInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(MediaPlayerContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            ArtistEntity DevonPortielje = new ArtistEntity()
            {
                Name = "Devon Portielje"
            };

//... at this part of code I create all my Artists, Bands, Tracks and Albums

            context.ArtistContextEntities.Add(DevonPortielje);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I then use Repository class to manipulate my DbSet's

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> contextDbSet;

        public Repository(MediaPlayerContext context)
        {
            contextDbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
//... some Repository methods
```

And Unit of Work to wrap my Repositories

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly MediaPlayerContext context;
        public IRepository<AlbumEntity> AlbumRepository { get; }
        public IRepository<ArtistEntity> ArtistRepository { get; }
        public IRepository<BandEntity> BandRepository { get; }
        public IRepository<TrackEntity> TrackRepository { get; }

        public UnitOfWork(MediaPlayerContext context, IRepository<AlbumEntity> albums,
            IRepository<ArtistEntity> artists, IRepository<BandEntity> bands,
            IRepository<TrackEntity> tracks)
        {
            this.context = context;
            AlbumRepository = albums;
            ArtistRepository = artists;
            BandRepository = bands;
            TrackRepository = tracks;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And after all of that I use Unit of Work in my Business Logic Services e.g.

```
    public class BandService : IBandService
    {
        readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

        public BandService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

//... Service methods
```

And finally I use those Services in my Controller:

```
    public class MediaPlayerController : Controller
    {
        IBandService BandService;
        IAlbumService AlbumService;
        ITrackService TrackService;

        public MediaPlayerController(IBandService bandService, IAlbumService albumService,
            ITrackService trackService)
        {
            BandService = bandService;
            AlbumService = albumService;
            TrackService = trackService;
        }

//... Controller ActionResult Methods that return Views
```

I add my Context to services collection in Startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MediaPlayerContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MediaPlayerDatabase")));

//...
```

The problem is that every time a new View is open a new Database is created because of these lines in my Initialize method.

```
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

But I can't find any other possible way to create my database (SetInitializer is not accessible anymore) and no change in my database will ever be reflected since it's always deleted and created anew. What do I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that your MediaPlayerInitializer.Initialize() method is static, you could create a static bool field and change it the first time to true and check it's value. Something like this:

```
private static bool initialized = false; // I know false is not needed

public static void Initialize(MediaPlayerContext context)
{
    if (initialized) {
        return;
    }

    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    ArtistEntity DevonPortielje = new ArtistEntity()
    {
        Name = "Devon Portielje"
    };

    //... at this part of code I create all my Artists, Bands, Tracks and Albums
    context.ArtistContextEntities.Add(DevonPortielje);

    context.SaveChanges();

    initialized = true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to use the same instance of MediaPlayerContext while I'm running my app. Your solution helps to avoid database recreation but what it does is it returns an empty context.

Comment: I don't understand. If you use the same instance of the MediaPlayerContext then the constructor is only called once. So Initialize would be called only once. So in my opinion you are not using the same instance (somewhere). Also I don't think using the same instance would be a good idea either way. By default dbContext is created as Scoped not Singleton if you want Singleton (to make sure you are using the same instance everywhere) you need to set it. (It is not advised), So I think the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I found where my problem was and you were right, it was in my service method, not in the context. I also added your 'verifier' and everything works properly now. I'm new to EF and your explanations were very useful, so thank you very much!